# How to add a string to a paragraph after a particular word Python

Tags: python, string, python-re

I am trying to insert a string after a specific word in a paragraph.

For example:
If the word I am looking at is `King` in the paragraph, I want to add `Arthur` right after it so it will be like:

```
King Arthur went on a mission
```

for all the lines that has `King` instead of

```
King went on a mission
```

Comment: `yourstring = yourstring.replace('King','King Arthur')` or `yourstring = re.sub(r'(King)','\\1 Arthur', yourstring)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses `re.sub` to substitute `King` (not followed by `Arthur`) with `King Arthur`):

```py
import re

s = "King went on a mission"

s = re.sub(r"\bKing\b(?!\s*Arthur)", "King Arthur", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
King Arthur went on a mission
```